# Find and Replace via GREP in InDesign in a specific manner

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am currently trying to layout a novel in InDesign. In the original text the chapters are headlined with "## Chapter X" because it is written in Markdown.

So I try to automate the layouting using GREP and try to apply a specific paragraph style to the headlines.

I use the following syntax to accomplish that:

```
## \w+ \d
```

But what it does, of course, is that the whole phrase "## Chapter X" is set in this style. Is there any way to apply the paragraph style AND remove the "##"?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In find field : (## )(\w+ \d)
In change field : $2;

Comment: Note that there is an extra needless semi-colon. Just coding the whole day ;)

Comment: I recognized it, but I didn't see it as an extra semicolon but I added a missing )

;)